# Datatable jQuery Issue(s)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I have a table and inside of that `table` I have a `<asp:DataGrid>`. I am trying to implement `DataTables`, which is a table plugin for jQuery. From what I have read on their site, all I have to do is simply add the 2 reference files and develop some `DataTable` script. I have done both, and I am not getting any results what so ever. I will post my code below, maybe I am missing something that my eyes are not catching:

**Mark-up**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="TableUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Search" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Clear" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <span style="color: #999; margin: 0 0 0 10px">
                <asp:Label ID="lblResultsCount" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bs-example text-center " id="Alert1" runat="server" visible="false">
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bs-example text-center " id="Alert2" runat="server" visible="false">
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table id="myTable" class="table tbody" runat="server" visible="false">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DataGrid ID="myGrid" runat="server"
                             CssClass="table table-sorting table-hover table-bordered datatable dataTable no-footer" 
                             Visible="false"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                             ForeColor="black"
                             HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                             HeaderStyle-ForeColor="black"
                             GridLines="None"
                             EnableViewState="false" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>                     
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myGrid').dataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "searching": true
    });
</script>
```

This is link that I followed to try and achieve this.. http://datatables.net/

Does anyone know what I could be missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What is your default control naming convention? If `ClientIDMode` is not `Static` then either set `ClientIDMode` of `myGrid` to `Static` or use server control identifier i.e. `<%=myGrid.ClientID%>` or in conjunction with `FindControl` as applicable

Comment: You should use ID of the table when initializing it, `$('#myTable').dataTable()`.

Comment: @haraman that did not do the trick for me...